# Deep learning models for classification, able to classify small image patches?

Tags: deep-learning, classification, keras, convolutional-neural-network, model-selection

I am currently working with classifying patterns, and though at good place to start would be using already established models such as VGG16, INCEPTION models and so on.. Problem that my images are pretty small.. They are in shape of (8,15,3)...

Any well established models able to handle this?

Comment: My advise would be to try any model you can. Having small images is a good thing since the dimension of your input is small. Any model should be fast to train.

Answer (score 0):

There is no model able to handle all the problem. For small images classification, you can just use model working on bigger ones.
For instance, I'm working with (20,20,3) images and Inception is my best model for now (Xception is about to be better when I'll have finish with it I guess). The only thing you have to do is to adapt your model to your problem.

If you're working with small images, you don't have to use a 256 convolutional layer, it's just overkill and can make your model weaker. If you're using inception, you must consider reduce the convolutional kernel numbers, maybe the number of different branches in each block and the number of block.

I hope it has been usefull for you !